# Having trouble activate Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghci

I'm a newbie here also at programming in general.
I just installed Stack via curl but got stuck at 'stack setup.' Although the terminal shows the Stack version, it gives me 'zsh: segmentation fault ' when I put 'stack setup ' , 'stack new project' or 'stack ghci'.

But I can use ghci and compile files.
The only reason that I can think of is, that a couple of years back, I was trying to install Haskell and failed. That might have messed up with the PATH, or there are multiple same files or something.
I was trying to figure out the cause and found that stack is not in the directory ' usr/local.bin.stack'. Does that have to do with the cause?
How should I deal with this situation?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify the behaviour you're observing with some command-line info. Might also be a good idea to show your OS, your shell, and the output of `which stack`.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [GHCup](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/) for installing and managing Haskell install. It does, as it says, one thing and does it well. And that thing is installing GHC, Cabal, HLS, and Stack.

The command to install it is:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
```

Then to get a nice user interface:

```
ghcup tui
```